# Using separate_rows() and tidyverse to remove punctuation and combine terms

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have, what I think, is an uncomplicated problem, but I can't seem to find a thread that addresses `separate_rows` with special punctuation using `sep =` . I have a large dataframe where I used text mining to extract the data science terms in each observation (N = 2,000). I then included that data as an appended column as data science solutions, `ds_solutions`. I'd like to separate these terms and then use `group_by` and `count =` to see if there are any trends/patterns for the different categories.

However, using `sep = ","`, I am unable to remove the other characters `[` and `'"'`, such that I have instances where the entry reads as `"['forecasting'"` rather than simply `forecasting`. Is this something I can do before separating out rows? Or after? Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

```
Project <- c("A", "B", "C")
Stage <- c("Pilot", "Pilot", "Idea")
ds_solutions <- c("['image recognition', 'ai', 'forecast', 'machine learning', 'machine learning model']", 
                  "['clustering', 'sentiment analysis', 'nlp', 'time series']", 
                  "['classifier', 'cluster analysis', 'classification', 'scraping', 'databases']")
sample <- data.frame(Project, Stage, ds_solutions)

Project Stage  ds_solutions
A       Pilot  ['image recognition', 'ai', 'forecast', 'machine learning', 'machine learning model']
B       Pilot  ['clustering', 'sentiment analysis', 'nlp', 'time series']
C       Idea   ['classifier', 'cluster analysis', 'classification', 'scraping', 'databases']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

sample %>% 
  mutate(ds_solutions = substr(ds_solutions, 3L, nchar(ds_solutions) - 2L)) %>% 
  separate_rows(ds_solutions, sep = "['\"],\\s*['\"]")
```

Comment: Hey @ekoam - It does! The output still includes each term enclosed in quotation marks (e.g., "linear regression" , "regression", "bayesian", etc). I think I can remove that once I include in a csv?

Comment: Hi @bjk127, I just updated the answer. How about this one?

Comment: It does! Thanks for the input. Not sure if I would have ever figured out that regular expression alone.

Comment: Hi @bjk127, glad to know that. If this or any other answer has solved your question, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Definitely. Thanks @ekoam!